# php cs fixer, how to run risky rules?

Tags: php, configuration, command-line-interface, php-cs-fixer

[PHP-CS-FIXER](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

Hi I am using php-cs-fixer for first time. I know that we have to set a .php_cs.dist file

This is a example file that i got from the git repository of **php-cs-fixer**.

```
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->exclude('somedir')
    ->in(__DIR__);

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules(array(
        '@Symfony' => true,
        'full_opening_tag' => false,
    ))
    ->setFinder($finder);
```

When i am running this command on **CLI**

**php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php_cs.dist --allow-risky**

It is saying that i need to give options to --allow-risky but in documentation it is nothing mention that how to set option for allow risky help me out guys.The sooner the better.

**my question**
  How to run risky rules? As there is nothing mentioned that how to use allow risky rule in php-cs-fixer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method is `->setRiskyAllowed(true)`. [Implementation code](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/eb54981b77cdfea93621e7c311f8a8e6fd979713/src/Config.php#L249).

Your code should look something like this:

```
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->exclude('somedir')
    ->in(__DIR__);

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRiskyAllowed(true)
    ->setRules(array(
        '@Symfony' => true,
        'full_opening_tag' => false,
    ))
    ->setFinder($finder);
```

I agree that this method is somewhat hidden, and I did not find it before I browsed the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you tell me how effectively php-cs-fixer works because it's not able to fix my php files correctly like indentation.

Comment: @Dherya I am afraid I can not tell you that. I've used it before and it worked like it should. This is something you may want to ask the author of the package at GitHub and is outside the scope of this question. If the provided information solved your initial problem, please accept the answer so others can see it in the future.

Answer (score 6):

We can enable the allow risky option in the command line like the following:

```
php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php_cs.dist --allow-risky=yes
```